# How make shader for dashed outline of rounded rectangle?

Tags: shader, hlsl, fragment-shader, cg, shader-graph

How make dashed outline for rounded rectangle like in figma?

[image: figma]

I tried wrote this, but I did only part with rounded rectangle and outline based on subtraction two rounded rectangles with different sizes.

I know about distance, frac and step, but how add dash and gap exactly by along outline line?

I tried use polar coordinates and take y value to fraction then step and after that I multiply with my contour which gives a needed result, but a little bit are not even, and I don't know how fix this.

[image: picture of result]

Answer (score 0):

I think sample a checkerboard texture would help. One part is pure white and the other is pure transparent. In the outline pass, instead of return a solid color, try to sample that texture by screen space coordinate

Comment: thanks for trying, but i don`t think how be with round corners in that case ?

Comment: I think if you are using smooth normals for outline extend, the corners would be rounded

Comment: Can you give me some code example of that approach? I just use shader-graph and into it use rounded rectangle node, and I understand how to write it in HLSL, but I don’t know about smooth normals in that case (I’m pretty new), and I can’t imagine how I can get a dash on the corner if the value will be taken from a checkboard texture.